# Berryboot and Kali/Parrot

Tags: pi-4, kali, berryboot, parrot

When I boot up either Kali or Parrot in berryboot, with both a monitor or my 7" touchscreen it boots the command line checks and then goes black, with parrot only displaying a pointer and kali nothing. What can I do? It's a pi 4

Comment: I seem to recall that there isn't a Kali compatible with the 4 yet, dunno if that has changed.  If you are not sure you should double check.

Comment: What size card do you have (16Gb is a good starting point)? Are you using the version for the Pi 4?  It can be downloaded via torrent from https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/#1493408272250-e17e9049-9ce8 One other thing to check - does your Pi boot a normal copy of Raspbian?

Comment: Yes, it boots raspian and the card is 32. Berryboot doesnt seem to support the newest kali image specifically for the 4. It causes it to corrupt i hear. I was wondering is using the Sticky fingers build would work.